# Creating a dropdown navbar using JavaServer Pages (jsp)

Tags: java, html, jsp, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dropdown menu navbar using jsp, from the following 3D array.

```
String[][][] navabr = new String[][][]
      {
             
              {{"pageA"}, {"page1", "subpageA_1_link_url"}, {"page2", "subpageA_2_link_url"}},
              {{"pageB"},{"page2", "subpageB_1_link_url"}, {"page2", "subpageB_2_link_url"}, {"page3", "supageB_3_link_url"}}
      };
```

This is the code snippet that i have implemented to try and produce it

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < navbar.length; i++){
if (navbar[i].length == 1){
    %><li ><a href="#<%= navbar[i][0][1]%>">Home</a></li>
  <% } %>
  <%if (navbar[i].length>1){
      %><li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><%= navbar[i][0][0]%> <span class="caret"></span></a>

      <%}
      for (int j = 1  ; j < navbar[i].length; j++){
          %>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#<%= navbar[i][j][1] %>"><%= navbar[i][j][0] %></a></li>

              </ul>
      <%}
}%>

</li>

</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

The problem that im having is that the drop down items are not getting looped, rather, only the last item is shown. For excample, for dropdown of pageA, only page 2 is shown and for the drop down of pageB only page 3 is shown. How do i fix it to have it show all dropdowns

Comment: what does `menus` has in it ?

Comment: @Swati was a typo, fixed now

Comment: I have run your code its working fine according to the data which you have in array . Can you elaborate more what happens when you clicked on your dropdown ? Also inspect your html generated in browsers element tab and check if all value are printed or not .And currently your html structure is wrong `<ul>` tag should come outside for loop.

Comment: thanks ey, it was the <ul> tag which was in the wrong position, now everything is perfect